# android- adjusting the layout with the device orientation

Tags: android, layout

Here is my Layout.But when I change the device orientation,although I am using dp in my layout ,I am not getting correct layout.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#F2F2F2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="90dp" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Username"
                android:textColor="#000000" >
            </TextView>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editname"
                android:layout_width="230dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </EditText>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Password"
                android:textColor="#000000" >
            </TextView>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editpassword"
                android:layout_width="230dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:password="true" >
            </EditText>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label"
            android:text="@string/RememberMe"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#111111"
            android:textStyle="bold"
             >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/Login"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/newuser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/signin"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/NotRegistered"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/forgtpasswd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/forgot_password_white_key"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="51dp"
        android:text="@string/ForgotPassword"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>
    <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressbar_Horizontal"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="12dp"
            android:max="100" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to change this layout according to the device' current orientation.How can I do this? Any help will be appreciated!!!

Comment: http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-size-and-orientation-of-the-screen

Comment: my problem is not with the getting size and orientation... adjusting layout according to that is my problem..

Comment: @Pasha: it didn't work..

Comment: @freshDroid What do you mean by adjusting layout? If you get some views looking wierd in landscape orientation, then maybe you just need to create separate layout file for landscapape mode and put right sizes there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can find good discussions on this topic, which could help you. For example, this is the good one: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/a640da2a01bdfde5?pli=1 .

And important for you, I think, is:

> Put the portrait one in res/layout. Put the landscape one in 
>   res/layout-land. Name them both the same (e.g., main.xml).

Comment: but then how to specify whether `main.xml` should be used from `res/layout` or `res/layout-land`.

Comment: If your device is in the landscape orientation, then main.xml from res/layout-land will be used. In the other case - from res/layout.

Comment: yup, it works. But how do I restore activity state during orientation change?

Comment: I can't understand. What do you mean?

Comment: for eg. I have two buttons `btnA` and `btnB`. On pressing each button, content of table changes to `contentA` or `contentB`. By default i.e. at the application launch, `contentA` gets displayed. Now I press `btnB`, so `contentB` will be displayed. But if I change the orientation, `contentA` gets displayed(i.e. activity gets re-launched.)

Comment: I think you have to put some analysis into "default" behavior. White "if" at application launch.

Answer (score 1):

Create layout in `resource` folder for different sizes like `Layout_large`, `Layout_large_land`,...